# Distribute Eclipse for multiple installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, distributed-computing

I hope someone can help me with this issue

I have an installion of custom plugins and  Android SDK in Eclipse Juno which is configured and running perfectly on my Computer. How can I distribute this as standardised Installation for other Computers?
I tried the "eclipse" way of copying the folder, but it ignores the custom plugins and Android SDK... as though they were never installed.
I have noticed that some repository files are created under the user, but since we are working in a lab and students can Login to any Computer, how can I optimize this so that they can work on their Projects in any Computer?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you copied the folder android-sdks, because is not just the adt plugin. The adt plugin without your android-sdk won't work.

Comment: I have also copied the SDK and pointed my SDK to it . Will the plugins are also transferred when the Eclipse is cpoied from master system to child system. 2) Is there a way where i install eclipse in one system and other systems can access it

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse stores its plugins, etc. under `.eclipse` directory of your user home. Therefore if you are talking about plain distribution of your eclipse compilation to the other machines - just copy both `eclipse` folder from where you've installed your eclipse + `.eclipse` folder from your user home.

But this solution won't work if you need *synchronization* between all copies of your eclipse compilation in the lab (nevertheless I believe you are talking about server OS in your lab that is designed to provide you access to the same your desktop no matter what terminal you use to login from - so moving your eclipse compilation there should be enough).

ps: note that transferring plugins are great, but the are lots of settings eclipse stores in the workspace; that means they are lost when transferring to another machine without your previous workspace copied also. So I'd suggest to install [Workspace Preferences Transferrer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-preferences-transferrer) plugin which allows to easely copy *almost* all of your settings while switching to the new workspace. It might be helpful in this situation...